# Appending a key value for URL android recieved from an INTENT

Tags: android, url, android-intent

### I need to append the URL before making a request

**I have used this for appending one key value as below**

```
String CITY;
CITY = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST");

String newurl = "?" + "Key=" + CITY.trim();
jsonobject=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://--URL--/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/"+newurl);
```

### Suppose when i need to append two key values at a time,How can it be done

```
String CITY;
String NAME;
    CITY = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST");
    NAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST2");
```

**How to appendd two values to the URL any Ideas ?**

Comment: I'm not sure to understant the question but, you can do the same no? `"?" + "Key="+CITY.trim() +"&OtherKey="+NAME.trim()`?

Comment: city=XXxXx&name=xxxx!!

Comment: variables that are not constant should NOT be CAPSIZED. This is reserved for constants by general programming standards in java.

Answer (score 1):

```
String newurl = "?" + "Key=" + CITY.trim() + "&Key2=" + NAME;
```

& character is used to separate key/value pairs. You may need URL encoding for some values as well.

Comment: It would be better if you use String.format() method instead of + based string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below:

```
String CITY;
String NAME;
CITY = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST");
NAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST2");

String newurl ="http://--URL--/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/?Key=" + CITY.trim() + "&Key2=" + NAME;
jsonobject=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(newurl);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ´&´ seperates key, value pairs in the `URL`. Make sure, you encode CITY and NAME, so that the result is still a valid URL:

```
String CITY;
String NAME;
CITY = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST");
NAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("REST2");

String newurl =
    "?" + "citykey=" + URLEncoder.encode(CITY.trim(), "UTF-8") +
    "&" + "namekey=" + URLEncoder.encode(NAME.trim(), "UTF-8");
jsonobject=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://--URL--/DescriptionSortedSearchRating/"+newurl);
```